# 404 Error not displaying as it should

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a project at hand but encountered an error.

I have RewriteRule to redirect `index.php?view=$1` to `/`. However, when I accessed a URL that is supposed to lead to a 404 Error, it displays the home page(index.php) instead.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php
ErrorDocument 500 /pages/errors/error_redirect.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/500.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Rewrite all URLs to non-extension URLs 
RewriteRule ^(admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?view=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The problem I am facing is that if I entered `http://localhost/asdasdads`, the browser led me to `http://localhost/` instead with unchanged URL in the browser but browser displaying index.php. It should have shown a 404 Error page.

I believe `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?view=$1 [L]` is the root of this problem. It is redirecting `/index.php?view=asdasdads` to `/index.php?view=` due to it is not found. I would want it to redirect to 404 instead.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aizat, try removing the unnecessary rewrite conditions, and give a try on this:

The simplest way to set a 404 error page is by directly setting a 404 error message in the ***.htaccess file*** itself:

> ErrorDocument 404 /404.php